# Returning HTML page in a JSON property in Spring Boot conditionally

Tags: spring, spring-boot

So I'm in a scenario writing Restful Services where based on request data, I've to return either a short string or HTML page IN A JSON variable. lets say like this:

```
response {
    result : YourRequestedString
}
```

OR

```
response {
    result : <html>...</html>
}
```

The decision of what will be returned is on server side.

So, is there a way that I can render my Thymeleaf (or any other maybe plain HTML) templates while I'm in the same controller method (directly or by calling some controller method that returns me the rendered page). That I can send back to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Leffchik I got it working, here's my setup with Thymeleaf so it can help others.

Setup htmlTemplateEngine

```
@Bean
public TemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine() {
final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());

return templateEngine;
}

private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("html/*"));
templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

return templateResolver;
}
```

Here's the html page in src/main/resources/templates/html/hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

RestController goes like this

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@Autowired
TemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine;

@RequestMapping("/testHello")
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
final org.thymeleaf.context.Context ctx = new org.thymeleaf.context.Context();

ctx.setVariable("name", name);

// Rendered template in String, You can now return in a JSON property
final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process("html/hello.html", ctx);

return ResponseEntity.ok().body(htmlContent);
}

}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Returning an HTML Page in a REST Api is not encouraged. But if you fancy you can return a `ResponseEntity<Response>` from your controller.

```
@GetMapping("/mymethod")
public ResponseEntity<Response> myMethod() {
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = null;

    if(string) {
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(getString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(getHtml(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return responseEntity;
}
```

Comment: I already am using ResponseEntity, how do I get that getHTML() method to return a rendered HTML template that is in my static/template folder.

Comment: @IbrahimFaiq, check [this guide](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html). It shows how you can manually render thymeleaf html template into String.